# Ubuntu 14.04.02 Mouse doesn't works

Tags: mouse

I have a problem with a fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04.02. The mouse only works at the first opened window. If I open the starter first the mouse work so that i can search for an application and start it. But if I open the Firefox now for example the mouse doesn't work in this window (can't close and so). Also if I open nautilus after the starter.

To get the mouse work I have to open the console first with CTRL+ALT+F1 and then go back to desktop with CTRL+ALT+F7

I use the mainboard Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD5H with an Intel i7-3770 and an Nvidia GTX 660. I also tried another mouse.

Hope someone know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Open a Terminal and run `sudo modprobe psmouse`.

Comment: This command changed nothing. Mouse is still not working in any window (so i had to go to the console and back to the desktop)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg unity ubuntu-desktop`. This will reinstall the X server, which manages your mouse, Unity, which is your GUI, and Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: I will try but I don't think this will change anything because it's the third time now which i installed ubuntu and always the same problem.

After i run the command i get this error:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

Comment: Run `apt-get install -f` to (hopefully) fix this problem.

Comment: This command says me that everything is fine... `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.`

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I figured out the problem happens due to my mouse, I only checked to connect a second one and use it.

My mouse which cause the problem is a Cyborg R.A.T 9.
After I searched a google I found this solution:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "R.A.T."
    MatchProduct "R.A.T.7|R.A.T.9"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Buttons” “17"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 7 6 12 0 0 0 16 17"
    Option "AutoReleaseButtons" "13 14 15"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

After creating the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-cyborgrat9.conf with this content it works fine.